# How to upgrade elastic stack in mac osx from 6.8.7 to 7.x (latest)

Tags: macos, elasticsearch, homebrew

I followed the elastic search doc for rolling upgrade in mac osx, [Link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/rolling-upgrades.html)

After taking snapshot and disabling the services, on upgrade using brew

I am getting: Warning: elasticsearch 6.8.7 already installed when doing `brew upgrade elasticsearch`.

`brew tap elastic/tap` and. `brew install elastic/tap/elasticsearch-full` is showing

```
elastic/tap/elasticsearch-full because conflicting formulae are installed.
  elasticsearch
```

Is `brew unlink elasticsearch` a safe practice to do?

**Manual Download:** I downloaded the elasticsearch 7.6 as tar file.

```
$ brew info elasticsearch

Data:    /usr/local/var/lib/elasticsearch/
Logs:    /usr/local/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_user.log
Plugins: /usr/local/var/elasticsearch/plugins/
Config:  /usr/local/etc/elasticsearch/
```

**where should I install the downloaded elasticsearch tar file and how can I restore my previous data**?

Took snapshot,